# Multiple view Controllers and dismiss the one at same time

Tags: ios, xamarin-studio

I have 3 viewControllers.(Let VC1,VC2,VC3)I have overloaded VC2 on VC1 from a button click event of VC1.Now I want to overload the VC3 on VC1 from the button click event of VC2 and  at the same time dismiss the VC2.
If I do these task separately it works fine..but when I do the same task concurrently It is not working..

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

So what I would recommend in this case is setting up a delegate protocol inside of VC2 that VC1 implements.

Something like:

```
@protocol SomeDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)requestsDismissalOfViewController;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SomeDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

So in VC2 you would call `[self.delegate requestsDismissalOfViewController];` and then in VC1 you would implement the `requestsDismissalOfViewController` method where you could dismiss VC2 and present VC3. Your best bet would be to present in the completion block of the dismissal.